# Angular does not set X-XSRF-TOKEN

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-security, angular17, x-xsrf-token

I am using **Angular 17** and **Spring Boot** with **Spring Security 6**.

As it states in Angular [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/http-security-xsrf-protection), when performing HTTP requests, an interceptor reads a token from a cookie, by default XSRF-TOKEN, and sets it as an HTTP header, X-XSRF-TOKEN. For this, in Angular I added

```
importProvidersFrom([
  HttpClientXsrfModule.withOptions({
    cookieName: "XSRF-TOKEN",
    headerName: "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
  }),
]),
```

Now taking a look at Spring [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/exploits/csrf.html#csrf-integration-javascript) I can construct this configuration for CSRF:

```
@Bean
fun filterChain(httpSecurity: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain {
    val tokenRepository = CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse()
    tokenRepository.cookiePath = "/"

    val delegate = XorCsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler()
    delegate.setCsrfRequestAttributeName("_csrf")

    val requestHandler = CsrfTokenRequestHandler(delegate::handle)

    return httpSecurity
        .csrf { configurer ->
            configurer
                .csrfTokenRepository(tokenRepository)
                .csrfTokenRequestHandler(requestHandler)
        }
        .cors(Customizer.withDefaults<CorsConfigurer<HttpSecurity>>())
        <...>
```

Also, CorsMapping, where Angular runs on `localhost:4200` port:

```
override fun addCorsMappings(registry: CorsRegistry) {
    registry
        .addMapping("/**")
        .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
        .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE")
        .allowedHeaders("Content-Type", "X-XSRF-TOKEN")
        .allowCredentials(true)
}
```

When trying to perform login:

[image]

I tried removing `http://` part from the request, but then Angular requests show:

[image]

When I perform login via **Postman**, everything works on first attempt - I get newly set XSRF-TOKEN in a cookie and X-XSRF-TOKEN in a header.

What am I missing here? Thanks.

Comment: " .allowedHeaders("Content-Type", "X-XSRF-TOKEN")"  Your screenshot is showing "X-Csrf-Token".  Not sure why that is... as you've got the angular middleware set to "X-XSRF-TOKEN".  (The camel-case thing is just dev-tools, but it shows "Csrf" instead of "Xsrf")

Comment: You should also check this for the SPA-specific Spring configuration: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/exploits/csrf.html#csrf-integration-javascript-spa-configuration

Comment: Also note that HttpClientXsrfModule will not work if you have absolute URLs.   If you use "environment" files, you'd set baseURL to relative.. just "."  This means that you can't really check this when running cross-domain.  (relative will be localhost:4200)  I turn off anti-csrf checks when running debug... and test locally by putting angular build into the localhost build of the server.  (so both served from same localhost port)

Comment: Hi, I do use environment files, I have `api_url: "http://localhost:8080/"`. If I set this to empty, my subsequent requests call to `localhost:4200` (I do see the X-XSRF-TOKEN now), but 404 error occurs, since localhost:4200 is not a backend endpoint. How am I supposed to make this work with my Spring Boot on different port?

Comment: Or it's better to deploy everything on same port? Is the real world scenario deploying on the same port and is a recommended approach?

Comment: yeah, I set development to absolute: https : // localhost:port, then turn off anti-csrf checks on the backend when it's also in development.  That means to test, I need to put the ng build version into the server build  (that's production environment so ".")  and turn anti-csrf checks back on for development mode on the local server. It's a pain, but once it's setup and tested you won't have to do that anymore... published version will all be production and same-origin, and you can remove CORS responses (which loosen your security).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've made it working via NGINX though - all the cors checks in backend are enabled, frontend does not shout that it's not the same origin request anymore. I've still got problems with websockets and cors though - i will be on the new thread if I cant find a solution. but thanks for the replies and help. cheers.

Answer (score 1):

In Angular you need to add an option { withCredentials: true } to the http call you do to the backend. This is for sending cookies ( outgoing credentials) in the request.

it would look like something like this

```
login(){
  const paylaod = {username:'admin', password:'1234'}
  const url = 'http://localhost:8080/auth/login'
  return this.http.post( url, payload, { withCredentials: true } )
}
```

For security reasons Angular by default dosent let you send the credentials without you explicity tell the http client to send the credentials.

(if your spring aplication has more endpoints that need those credentials , in angular you need to put whithCredentials: true to all the http calls you make to send to the backend those credentials)

Comment: just a note that "withCredentials: true" is only need for cross-domain.  (which localhosts at different ports are so this answer is very relevant.)  Angular doesn't prevent, that's just the way browsers deal with cross-site fetches.... (by default no cookies will be sent unless that option is set)

Comment: Hi, yes, I do pass `withCredentials: true` with every request. My credentials are passed successfully. Please take a look at my response - I did receive JSESSIONID.